# how to implement collection interface

Tags: collections

In an institute following information is maintained about the students:

Student Class

Roll Number (Unique identifier of the student)
First Name
Last Name
Year Of Study
Activity Choice
For each of the following scenarios, specify which of the four core collection interfaces will be most appropriate and why. If you feel, more than one interface is suitable, you can mention all of them. Also describe briefly, why you think so.

1.Every week, a student is chosen at random as in charge of the Mess Food committee.

2.The students are allowed to choose a recreation activity to be provided by the institute in the common room. List of unique activities is to be prepared to be provided by the institute.

3.We need to know how many students have opted for each activity. So count the number of students who have the same activity.

4.The institute provides a career counselor for students who visit the institute once a week. Each student can book a slot with the counselor. Create a waiting list of students for the forthcoming weekly visit.

Comment: And now you expect us to do your homework?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you want to read some guidelines before post a new question or editing this. You can learn about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)